# Double entries for android device in "Available Devices" (Kubuntu 14.10)

Tags: usb, kubuntu, android

I'm running Kubuntu 14.10 and trying to make an MTP connection (over a USB cable) to an LGP705 Android phone. At one time I had the connection working, but no longer.  The problem I now have is that the device icon in "Available Devices" appears twice, but neither of these appearances is usable. One of them has the label LG-P705; the other has no label.  How can I get back to having a single device in the list?

Comment: I have 3 entries out of which only 1 works. Other has errors `The file or folder udi=/org/kde/solid/udev/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.1 does not exist.`